# How to ask turtles to do different actions according to ticks

Tags: netlogo

I want to ask you if the time step of my model is per month , and I want to divide the actions , the first 6 months the turtle will do some thing and the second six months other action,

what I know if I want to ask the turtle to do every 6 months the same action

```
  if ticks mod 6 = 0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what's the question again? What "doesn't work" with that?

Comment: I dont know how to do it what I did is (( if ticks mod 6 = 0 [ asked turtles [.....)) but it give me same action every 6 months

Comment: "what I know if I want to ask the turtle to do every 6 months the same action" - so what's wrong with that?

Comment: what I need to do is every year is divided to two 6 months and each 6 months turtles will do action completely different from the other 6 months

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question right, you can just do:

```
if ticks < 6 [
  do-one-action
]
if ticks >= 6 [
  do-other-action
]
```

Edit: Just saw your comments. If you want to alternate actions every 6 ticks, you could do:

```
if ticks mod 12 < 6 [
  do-one-action
]

if ticks mod 12 >= 6 [
  do-other-action
]
```

If `ticks` tells us the number of months that have passed in the simulation, then `ticks mod 12` tell us which month in the current year it is (e.g. 0, 1, 2, ... 11). So `if ticks mod 12 < 6` says "if we're in the first 6 months of the current year".

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) it helped me to understand the way to use ticks , thanks again

Comment: You're very welcome! If it solved, be sure to check it as correct. It helps people see what questions have been successfully answered.